# Catel show dialog window inside a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

Please Help.
I put this construction in any method to main ViewModel

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
     _visualizerService.ShowDialog(new PurchaseWindowViewModel());
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

And i have exception in PurchaseWindowViewModel.xaml.cs

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional
>   information: Not access to object Freezable
>   "Catel.Windows.Media.Effects.GrayscaleEffect"

through the threads, as it can not be frozen.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a window on a separate thread is hardly ever required and only "required" in edge-case scenarios. Please update your question why you want to use a window on a non-ui thread if the answer below does not solve your issue.

I recommend that you use this code instead:

`await _visualizerService.ShowDialogAsync<PurchaseWindowViewModel>();`

or non async:

`_visualizerService.ShowDialog<PurchaseWindowViewModel>();`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found my mistake. I called dialog window from System.timers event handler.  I changed timer on DispatcherTimer and all working.